# CSS button in IE9 - different text vertical align

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Two same tags have different alignment in IE9. I've stored code in http://jsfiddle.net/9B2hK/, but when I see it in IE9 there both buttons have 5px intead on 6px. If I remove one line break tag, text alignment in second tag became OK.

[image]

Few words about my task. I need buttons styled by css. I've created .btn class which is used for anchor tag, for input tag with types "submit" and "button". I need button height be the same with text input field, so I've set it's height 20px. Also because I need it works in chrome and others I set line-height=14px and padding=3px for top and bottom to align text. I've tried to use vertical-align, but for some browsers it doesn't work good. But my styles works strange in IE9. I've removed unnecessary tags from my page and here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-size: 11px;
        font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif
    }
    .btn {
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 14px;
        padding: 3px 10px 3px;
        font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background-color: #5675B5;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="btn">Search</span>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <span class="btn">Search</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Decided decrease height to 19px and remove line-height. Button became more asymmetric but difference in IE disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line-height and use css transform property.

```
.btn {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    padding: 3px 10px 3px;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #5675B5;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```